# Shrink Database fail

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Hi All I Had written a Script to Shrink database

```
DECLARE @string     NVARCHAR(4000), 
        @Strt       INT ,
        @END        INT ,
        @DBName     NVARCHAR(255),
        @Log_Size   DECIMAL(18,5),
        @Log_Name   NVARCHAR(25),
        @String_sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #t (srno INT IDENTITY(1,1),filename NVARCHAR(255),DBNAME NVARCHAR(50))  
CREATE TABLE #Tmp_logfile (fileName NVARCHAR(25),file_size DECIMAL(12,5),log_Name NVARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO #Tmp_logfile (fileName,file_size,log_Name)

SELECT a.NAME , CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,5),ROUND(b.size/128.000,5)),b.name 
FROM SYS.DATABASES  a 
INNER JOIN  SYS.MASTER_FILES b ON a.database_id=b.database_id
WHERE a.database_id > 4 AND b.file_id =2 

INSERT INTO #t
SELECT 
'USE [' + d.name + N']' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ 'DBCC SHRINKFILE (N''' + mf.name + N''' , 1, TRUNCATEONLY) ' 
+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) as fileName,d.name
FROM sys.master_files mf 
JOIN sys.databases d 
ON mf.database_id = d.database_id 
WHERE d.database_id > 4 AND mf.file_id=2;

SET @Strt=1
SELECT @END= Max(Srno)FROM #t

While @Strt<=@END
BEGIN
    SELECT  @string= FileName,@DBName= DBNAME FROM #t WHERE srno= @Strt
    SELECT  @Log_Size= file_size FROM #Tmp_logfile WHERE fileName=  @DBName

    IF @Log_Size > 10000 BEGIN   -- Limit The Log Size After which Log file to be Shrink

    PRINT (@string)
    EXECUTE (@string)
END
SET @Strt=@Strt+1

END       ---- SHRINKING Log File END Here
```

Here for Example I had Put a condition where log file greater then 10 GB it    will shrink The Database Log File.

But the Problem is Sometime it's fail while Running In Sql Agent don't know what Mistake  I'm Making.Any Help would be Appreciated.

Comment: what is the error  ?

Comment: @TheGameiswar DB_Name Is Full due to log_Backup it's showing in Sql Agent

Comment: Please share exact error message

Comment: @TheGameiswar  Following are The error USE [DB_NAME]  DBCC SHRINKFILE DB_NAME_log<c/> 1<c/> TRUNCATEONLY) [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  Cannot shrink log file 2 (DB_NAME_log) because of minimum log space required. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 9009)  DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages<c/> contact your system administrator. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 2528).  The step succeeded.,00:00:49,0,2528,,,,0

Comment: What is your database recovery model and what dbcc loginfo for this database says?

Comment: Why are you shrinking log files? If your database is using "Full" or "Bulk-Logged" recovery model then you need to **backup** log files. Secondly, if the files keep growing back up, what is the purpose of shrinking them (provided you do log backups)? Useful link: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/

Comment: @Alex The reason Behind Shrinking Is Drive On which Sql server is Install is Having Less Space so to Avoid Issue related to Space I Had To Shrink log file I have no Other choice.Thanks for Link but I already visit this Link a long Back ago.Except Shrinking I Had No other choice

Comment: @sepupic Database Recovery Model is SIMPLE before Shrinking and After Shrinking Make it FULL. And DBCC Loginfo doesn't return any error

Comment: dbcc loginfo should NOT return any error. I asked you about your log VLFs: how many VLFs do you have, how many of them have status 2, where are they located (at the beginning or at the end of your log file)

Comment: @sepupic Only 2 VLF's  at Beginning have status 2

Comment: >>>And I don't understand VLF's<<< That is interesting. Are you sure you **really need** to do this shrink? You use it with TRUNCATEONLY, and BOL says: The TRUNCATEONLY option does not move information in the log, but does remove inactive VLFs from the end of the log file. This option is not supported for FILESTREAM filegroup containers.So you want to do smth that you don't know what it means?

Comment: >>>Only 2 VLF's at Beginning have status 2. Ok, you have 2 VLFs with status 2, but are there any others? I asked you how many VLFs there are and you did not answer. DBCC LOGINFO shows you 1 row for each VLF, so your log has as many VLFs as your dbcc command rows output

Comment: @sepupic I Need to Shrink just I don't Have The Space on Server Machine

Comment: So how many rows did  DBCC LOGINFO return?

Answer (score 0):

Have created a proc for shrinking databases. It doesn't check the log size. It checks the log percentage as 60. Currently written as static.

Runs smoothly. Can work as an alternative to your proc.

```
 Create Proc ShrinkDatabase
 As
Begin
Declare @DBName nvarchar(100),@sQuery nvarchar(max)
Declare @LogFileName nvarchar(100)=''

Create table #tblTemp (id int identity(1,1),DatabaseName nvarchar(100),LogSize decimal(10,2),LogPercent decimal(10,2), IsHandled int)

Insert into #tblTemp (DatabaseName,LogSize,LogPercent,IsHandled) 
Exec ('DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)');

Update #tblTemp Set IsHandled=0;

Delete from #tblTemp WHERE DatabaseName IN 
('master','model','msdb','tempdb','ReportServer$MSSQLSERVER14','ReportServer$MSSQLSERVER14TempDB',
'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS','ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB','ReportServer','ReportServerTempDB');

While (Select count(*) from #tblTemp Where LogPercent > 60 and IsHandled=0) > 0
Begin
    Select Top 1 @DBName=DatabaseName from #tblTemp Where LogPercent > 60 And IsHandled=0

    Set @sQuery=' USE ' + @DbName + '; '
    Exec (@sQuery)

    SELECT @LogFileName=name FROM sys.master_files 
    WHERE database_id = (Select database_id from sys.databases Where name=@DbName) AND type = 1;

    Set @sQuery=@sQuery + ' ALTER DATABASE '+@DBName+'  SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;  '
    Set @sQuery=@sQuery + ' DBCC SHRINKFILE ('+@LogFileName+') WITH NO_INFOMSGS ; '
    Set @sQuery=@sQuery + ' ALTER DATABASE '+@DBName+'  SET RECOVERY FULL;'

    --Print (@sQuery)
    Exec (@sQuery)

    Print 'Shrunk Database: ' + @DBName

    Update #tblTemp Set IsHandled=1 Where DatabaseName=@DbName And LogPercent > 60 And IsHandled=0
End
 Drop table #tblTemp
End
Go
```

Comment: Thanks there was some space issue on server So I can't go for %.and I found The Issue and rectified the Issue.